# Sinon stub throws "TypeError: Cannot redefine property"

Tags: javascript, sinon

I'm using the NPM package [Jose](https://github.com/panva/jose) (version v1.28.0) in one of my NodeJS applications. Recently my renovate bot tried to update it to the next major version 2.0.2. Sadly my unit tests with [Sinon](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon) don't work anymore with this version. My application itself works without any problems...

I'm getting the following error:

> ```
> TypeError: Cannot redefine property: decode
>     at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
> ```

This is the code that triggers the error:

```
 import { JWT, JWK } from 'jose';
 // other code ...
 sandbox.stub(JWT, 'decode').returns(decodedResult);
```

I'm at a loss at what I need to change in the unit test to get it working again. If the 'decode' method is not stubbed it will always throw an error with my fake input values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sinon works by re-defining properties, the property has been made intentionally non-enumerable but in the process also not configurable. This is soon to be fixed in v2.0.3

Comment: Works again with v2.0.3!

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the document of JWT object, it doesn't has a "decode" function, so you cannot stub it.

https://github.com/panva/jose/blob/master/docs/README.md#jwt-json-web-token

Comment: If you check the documentation again you can find the "decode" function. It is just hidden under the point "Need to peak into a JWT without verifying it? (Click to expand)"