# jsonwebtoken 9.0.0 - getting error: TypeError: Cannot redefine property: decode - when trying to stub

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, mocha.js, sinon

so `npm audit` just found [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) to have a security vulnerbility. [The solution](https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-27h2-hvpr-p74q) is to update to version `9.0.0` - which I did.

However, my mocha tests are not passing now. During a `beforeEach`, I am trying to stub the `decode` function using `sinon.stub`, which now throws this TypeError:

`TypeError: Cannot redefine property: decode`

The beforeEach:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

beforeEach(function () {
  this.sinon.stub(jwt, 'verify').returns({ email: 'email@email.com' });
  this.sinon.stub(jwt, 'decode').returns({ header: { alg: 'RS256', typ: 'JWT', kid: 'MOCKKID' } });
  this.sinon.stub(jwks, 'getKey').returns('some mock certificate');
  this.sinon.stub(T, 'expired');
});
```

I assume that stubbing `verify` still works, since the error only throws on the next line when I try to stub `decode`

Yes, there is a [post with similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64131445/sinon-stub-throws-typeerror-cannot-redefine-property), but it's two years old, and the accepted answer is that "this is soon to be fixed in a future version". So not really relevant anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `jsonwebtoken` v9.0.0 makes the `decode` function non-enumerable and non-configurable, see [v9.0.0/index.js#L9](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/blob/v9.0.0/index.js#L9)

`index.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  verify: require('./verify'),
  sign: require('./sign'),
  JsonWebTokenError: require('./lib/JsonWebTokenError'),
  NotBeforeError: require('./lib/NotBeforeError'),
  TokenExpiredError: require('./lib/TokenExpiredError'),
};

Object.defineProperty(module.exports, 'decode', {
  enumerable: false,
  value: require('./decode'),
});
```

From the documentation [Non-configurable properties created by Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_redefine_property#non-configurable_properties_created_by_object.defineproperty)

> The `Object.defineProperty()` creates non-configurable properties if you haven't specified them as configurable.

Which means the `configurable: false` is the default. That's why `sinon.stub(jwt, 'decode')` doesn't work anymore.

And there is [PR](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/pull/876) trying to fix it to allow the `decode` function to be stubbed. This PR makes the `decode` configurable:

```js
Object.defineProperty(module.exports, 'decode', {
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: true,
  value: require('./decode'),
});
```

There is a temporary solution, you can create your own jwt utils module and stub your own jwt utils.

E.g.

`jwt-repack.js`:

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const decode = require('jsonwebtoken').decode;

module.exports = {
  ...jwt,
  decode
};
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
const sinon = require('sinon');
const jwt = require('./jwt-repack');

it('should pass', () => {
  sinon.stub(jwt, 'decode').returns({ header: { alg: 'RS256', typ: 'JWT', kid: 'MOCKKID' } });

  const actual = jwt.decode();
  sinon.assert.match(actual, { header: { alg: 'RS256', typ: 'JWT', kid: 'MOCKKID' } });
});
```

package versions:

```json
"jsonwebtoken9": "npm:jsonwebtoken@^9.0.0",
"sinon": "^8.1.1",
```